# Sending multiple transactions in a block using Hardhat test network

Tags: transactions, testnets, hardhat, test

Hardhat's test network, `defaultNetwork: "hardhat"` in config, automatically mines a block every time a transaction is sent by default.

This is problematic for situations where I want to test functionalities where multiple transactions need to be in the same block.

How can I set/configure hardhat to not automatically mine transactions during tests and control when the test network actually mines a block?

Comment: In order to do it on a single test level and not the entire project configuration you can use ‘evm_setAutomine‘

Answer (score 1):

Set a mining mode in the configuration to tell it how to mine.

[Documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference#mining-modes) states:

You can configure the mining behavior under your Hardhat Network settings:

```json
networks: {
  hardhat: {
    mining: {
      auto: false,
      interval: 5000
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, automining is disabled and interval mining is set so that a new block is generated every 5 seconds. You can also configure interval mining to generate a new block after a random delay:

```json
networks: {
  hardhat: {
    mining: {
      auto: false,
      interval: [3000, 6000]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, a new block will be mined after a random delay of between 3 and 6 seconds. For example, the first block could be mined after 4 seconds, the second block 5.5 seconds after that, and so on.

**Manual mining**

You can disable both mining modes like this:

```json
networks: {
  hardhat: {
    mining: {
      auto: false,
      interval: 0
    }
  }
}
```

This means that no new blocks will be mined by the Hardhat Network, but you can manually mine new blocks using the evm_mine RPC method. This will generate a new block that will include as many pending transactions as possible.